# how to change the phonegap/cordova status bar background on startup(splash screen)?

Tags: android, cordova, statusbar

im using the latest official version of android on my testing mobile and i'm developping an application using cordova 6.

well everything works great but during the  startup (the first 3 seconds/ the time of displaying the splash screen) i get a black status bar (the default one) untill the app is fully showed then the color of status bar changes to the color i set on my configuration file.

my question is how to change the color of the status bar during the startup ? what about hide it totally untill it finish displaying splash screen ?

Comment: Just confirming ... you want the title bar there during normal operation of your app (after splash screen)? So setting your app to FULL SCREEN probably isn't the right answer?

Comment: @SteveKennedy no i want to control background color before the the normal operation of the app.

Answer (score -1):

You can control style of status bar using the plugin

https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-statusbar

Set the required color of status bar in your config.xml by setting the preference

```
<preference name="StatusBarBackgroundColor" value="#000000" />
```

After that you can change the color like below in your code if you have installed the above mentioned plugin.

```
StatusBar.backgroundColorByName("red");
```

Regarding hiding the status bar totally during splash screen,

```
<preference name="fullscreen" value="true"/>
```

And you can show the status bar using code (Not tested)

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
function onDeviceReady() {
    StatusBar.show();
}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: did you read my question ? i can control the backgroud color of the status bar using the you mentioned  but i can do that during the display of the splash screen .

Comment: @Hamzar Setting preference will change the status bar color of the app even in splash screen. Then you can change the color as per your requirement from your code. Also I have update my answer regarding hiding the status bar.